# Conditional grouping in XSLT

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0, muenchian-grouping

Request your help to transform XML using XSLT 2

My input XML looks like below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <Batch_number>1234</Batch_number>
        <Name>David</Name>
        <Assignment>
            <type>A</type>
            <name>New York</name>
        </Assignment>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Batch_number>1234</Batch_number>
        <Name>David</Name>
        <Assignment>
            <type>B</type>
            <name>Boston</name>
        </Assignment>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Batch_number>1234</Batch_number>
        <Name>David</Name>
        <Assignment>
            <type>C</type>
            <name>Chicago</name>
        </Assignment>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Batch_number>78698</Batch_number>
        <Name>Karen</Name>
        <Assignment>
            <type>C</type>
            <name>Chicago</name>
        </Assignment>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

Desired output looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Worker>
    <Batch_number>1234</Batch_number>
    <Name>David</Name>
    <Assignment>
            <type>A</type>
            <name>New York</name>
        </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
            <type>B</type>
            <name>Boston</name>
        </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
            <type>C</type>
            <name>Chicago</name>
        </Assignment>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    <Batch_number>78698</Batch_number>
    <Name>Karen</Name>
    <Assignment>
            <type>C</type>
            <name>Chicago</name>
        </Assignment>
</Worker>
```

Condition for transformation is:

If child node `<Worker>`with same `<Batch_number>`exists in input file, all `Assignment` nodes for same `<Batch_number>` should be grouped together under one `Worker` child node right after `<Batch_number>` and `<Name>`

Can someone help me write the correct code to achieve this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your desired output XML is not *well-formed*, here is an XSLT-2.0 solution which suffices your special needs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Workers">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Worker" group-by="Batch_number">
            <Worker>
                <Batch_number><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" /></Batch_number>
                <Name><xsl:value-of select="current()/Name" /></Name>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/Assignment" />
            </Worker>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Its output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Worker>
    <Batch_number>1234</Batch_number>
    <Name>David</Name>
    <Assignment>
        <type>A</type>
        <name>New York</name>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
        <type>B</type>
        <name>Boston</name>
    </Assignment>
    <Assignment>
        <type>C</type>
        <name>Chicago</name>
    </Assignment>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    <Batch_number>78698</Batch_number>
    <Name>Karen</Name>
    <Assignment>
        <type>C</type>
        <name>Chicago</name>
    </Assignment>
</Worker>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot zx485. I modified your piece of code slightly to add a parent node to have well-formed XML. thanks for pointing out that to me.

Comment: by any chance, could you explain what does current-grouping-key(), current(), current(), current-group(). Though i got what i wanted, i'm unable to understand how this code works. Any additional details would help me. Thanks again.

Comment: Explaining this would be beyond SO's purpose. There are others which have done this better than I could possibly do. So [have a look here at XML.com](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html).

Comment: @Anoop if you are coding in XSLT without access to some kind of reference book or online resource that explains what each of the instructions and functions does, that would give me serious concern. It's like driving a car without taking driivng lessons.

Comment: @MichaelKay Point taken. I'm referring W3 schools and few online blogs and materials to learn XSLT. Please can you recommend any study materials or books for me to learn XSLT2.0 and XSLT3.0?

Comment: Well, my first recommendation would be my own book, XSLT 2.0 Programmer's Reference from Wiley. It's a very comprehensive reference, except that it doesn't cover 3.0. There are other books like the one from Jeni Tennison that provide a more gentle tutorial approach. For 3.0 there's less material available. Don't be afraid to read the W3C spec (except for streamability analysis, which is truly fearsome).

Comment: There's a quick reference to all the XSLT 3.0 instructions at http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!xsl-elements, with links to the W3C spec if you need it. For XPath functions, I would go straight to the W3C spec at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/ -- but note that this doesn't include XSLT-specific functions like current() and current-group().

Comment: @Anoop, there is also https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm which is an introduction to XSLT 1 and 2 and certainly covers grouping.

Comment: @zx485, the `<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">` with the nested `<xsl:copy-of select="current()/Assignment" />` could be shortened to simply use `<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/Assignment"/>` directly.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Thanks. I changed that in the answer.